# bash create dir with sequential numbers

Tags: macos, bash, mkdir

I am creating a script to run on OS X which will be run often by a novice user, and so want to protect a directory structure by creating a fresh one each time with an n+1 over the last:

`target001` with the next run creating `target002`

I have so far:

```
lastDir=$(find /tmp/target* | tail -1 | cut -c 6-)
let n=$n+1
mkdir "$lastDir""$n"
```

However, the math isn't working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pipes and subprocesses:

```
targets=( /tmp/target* )                # all dirs in an array
lastdir=${targets[@]: (-1):1}           # select filename from last array element
lastdir=${lastdir##*/}                  # remove path
lastnumber=${lastdir/target/}           # remove 'target'
lastnumber=00$(( 10#$lastnumber + 1 ))  # increment number (base 10), add leading zeros

mkdir /tmp/target${lastnumber: -3}      # make dir; last 3 chars from lastnumber
```

A version with 2 parameters:

```
path='/tmp/x/y/z'                       # path without last part
basename='target'                       # last part

targets=( $path/${basename}* )          # all dirs in an array
lastdir=${targets[@]: (-1):1}           # select path from last entry
lastdir=${lastdir##*/}                  # select filename
lastnumber=${lastdir/$basename/}        # remove 'target'
lastnumber=00$(( 10#$lastnumber + 1 ))  # increment number (base 10), add leading zeros

mkdir $path/$basename${lastnumber: -3}  # make dir; last 3 chars from lastnumber
```

Comment: I get `-bash: targets: bad array subscript` when declaring `lastdir`. I'm using GNU bash v3 on OS X

Comment: Thanks. That is right for Bash 4.1 and below. Solution changed.

Comment: Thanks @fgm Can I also ask how the "remove path" code works, as I need to use a different path in the production environment.

Comment: I added a second version for an arbitrary path.

Comment: I got it now thanks @fgm. I'm learning. I had to use unset to not be getting the odd results I was seeing in testing.

Answer (score 2):

What about
[`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp)?

```
Create  a  temporary  file  or directory, safely, and print its name.
TEMPLATE must contain at least 3 consecutive `X's in last  component.
If  TEMPLATE  is  not  specified, use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX, and --tmpdir is
implied.  Files are created u+rw, and directories u+rwx, minus  umask
restrictions.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am glad to be made aware of this. Only concern in this instance is the random suffix rather than an incrementation. The `mktemp` will definitely have other uses to me though.

Answer (score 2):

Use this line to calculate the new sequence number:

```
...
n=$(printf "%03d" $(( 10#$n + 1 )) )
mkdir "$lastDir""$n"
```

10# to force base 10 [arithmetic](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr). Provided $n beeing the last secuence already e.g. "001".

Comment: I get `target001001` as a result of this

Comment: I only focused my answer on your math problem. The ... means you have to do some work yourself like extracting **$lastDir** (file name minus sequence e.g. "/tmp/target") and **$n** (e.g. "001"). Given that, my solution will increment the sequence and mk the dir.

Comment: Re-wrote for complete solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239753/1207958](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239753/1207958)

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution using extended test [[ and BASH_REMATCH :

```
[[ $(find /tmp/target* | tail -1) =~ ^(.*)([0-9]{3})$ ]]
mkdir $(printf "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}%03d" $(( 10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1 )) )
```

Provided /tmp/target001 is your directory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
lastDir=$(find /tmp/target* | tail -1)
let n=1+${lastDir##/tmp/target}
mkdir /tmp/target$(printf "%03d" $n)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this as it seems to want to not increment and `mkdir /tmp/target001`