# Creating directories with increasing name using mkdir

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I'd like to have a bash script that would create folder called "exam_folder" and if this folder already exists (I'd run the script again for example), the script would create "exam_folder_1" and if that folder exists I want the script to create "exam_folder_2" and so on and on. I'd like to have it smartly :)
I got something like this:

```
function create_folder {

if [ -d "$1" ]; then # if exists
    mkdir $1_`i_max` # function i_max would find out the max number and add 1
else 
    mkdir $1
fi }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239753/1207958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
max=`ls -1d exam_folder* | tr -dc '[0-9\n]' | sort -k 1,1n | tail -1`
mkdir exam_folder_$((max + 1))
```

Note that it won't fill 'holes' in the sequence, if your'e OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Two ansers: The compatible [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and the pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

***Last edit:*** Make regexp more precise and correct some counting bugs.

Something like:

```
create_folder() {
    if [ -e "$1" ] ;then
        counter=1;
        while [ -e "$1-$counter" ] ;do 
            counter=$((counter+1))
            done
        mkdir "$1-$counter";
    else
        mkdir "$1";
    fi;
}
```

could do:

```
$ ls -ltr /tmp |grep foo
$ create_folder /tmp/foo\ bar
$ create_folder /tmp/foo\ bar
$ create_folder /tmp/foo\ bar
$ ls -ltr /tmp |grep foo
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user   4096  1 mai 10:53 foo bar
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user   4096  1 mai 10:53 foo bar-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user   4096  1 mai 10:53 foo bar-2
```

or with a better formatting and another way of counting (quicker if many directories exists as it use specialized count function, but longer if else because of forks.):

```
create_folder() {
    if [ -e "$1" ] ;then
        counter=`/bin/ls -1 "$1" "$1-"* 2>&1 | grep -E "^$1(-[0-9]*)?" | wc -l`;
        nname="`printf "%s-%04d" "$1" $counter`";
        mkdir "$nname";
    else
        mkdir "$1";
    fi;
}
```

This was tested under different [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) implementations: [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [dash](/questions/tagged/dash), [ash](/questions/tagged/ash) and [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)

```
$ create_folder /tmp/test
$ ls -ltr /tmp/| grep test
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:25 test

$ create_folder /tmp/test
$ create_folder /tmp/test
$ ls -ltr /tmp/| grep test
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:25 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:26 test-0001
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:26 test-0002
```

And with dirname containing whitespaces:

```
$ create_folder "foo bar"
$ create_folder "foo bar"
$ create_folder "foo bar"
$ create_folder "foo bar"
$ ls -ltr | grep foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:35 foo bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:35 foo bar-0001
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:35 foo bar-0002
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 30 13:35 foo bar-0003
```

#### And for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) fans:

```
create_folder() {
    local -a list
    local counter nname
    if [ -e "$1" ] ;then
        list=("$1-"*)
        list=(${list[@]// /_})
        list=(${list[@]//*\*})
        counter=$((${#list[@]}+1))
        printf -v nname "%s-%04d" "$1" $counter
        mkdir "$nname";
    else
        mkdir "$1";
    fi;
}
```

Very quick, no fork and nice formatting:

```
$ create_folder "/tmp/foo bar"
$ create_folder "/tmp/foo bar"
$ create_folder "/tmp/foo bar"
$ create_folder "/tmp/foo bar"

$ ls -ltr /tmp/ | tail -n 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096  1 mai 11:17 foo bar
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096  1 mai 11:17 foo bar-0001
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096  1 mai 11:17 foo bar-0002
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096  1 mai 11:17 foo bar-0003
```

Comment: Nono, [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). That aside, try running `create_folder "foo bar"` two and three times and see what else is wrong with your code.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Ok, I've missed one double quote: `printf "%s-%04d" "$1"`. The main advantage of this instead of *pure bash*, is that work under busybox, as well.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth As there is a `grep` between `ls` and `wc -l`, the *don't parse ls output* does not matter here, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It does, and it working somehow under busybox is a bad excuse for writing unnecessary ugly code. Also, since you only count lines, if there are folders like `foo barquux` it will take those into account and unnecessarily hop over those indices (not wrong behaviour, but not what a user might expect).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I'm not sure my code is uglier than your code  ( I find using variable name like `counter` and `nname` more readable than `d` and `i` ;-) . At all it work with or without fork and stay compatible.

Comment: I was just referring to the unnecessary use of `ls` et al, not readability. Your new top solutions is unarguably prettier and easier to read, but fills existing holes while mine finds the top counter, which is a matter of preference :-) (Btw, you can drop the superfluous semicolons).

Answer (score 0):

This should work under any POSIX-compliant shell (although I am not 100% certain about the `[ "$foo" -eq "$foo" ]` is-number-check). I gave it a quick test under `dash` and `busybox' ash`.

```
create_folder()
{
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        i=0
        for d in "$1"_*; do
            _i="${d##*_}"
            [ "${_i}" -eq "${_i}" ] 2>/dev/null && i="${_i}"
        done
        i=$((i+1))
        mkdir "$1_${i}"
    else
        mkdir "$1"
    fi
}
```